# How to check if cookie is set?

Tags: cookies

I've got this code that sets me cookies:

```
        $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
        $id = $row["id"];   
        session_register('id'); 
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        $username = $row["login_email"];   
        session_register('login_email'); 
        $_SESSION['login_email'] = $email;
        mysql_query("UPDATE members SET lastlogin=now() WHERE id='$id'");
```

And I'm trying to do this at the top of the page,which goes after session_start():

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("Location: http://www.google.com");
    exit();
}
```

But it doesn't redirect me to google, what could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

In the code you posted, you never set `$_SESSION['username']`  there is only `$username = $row["login_email"];`

Maybe `$_SESSION['username'] = $row["login_email"];` will do the trick?